# Mod_PageSpeed module causing browser caching of 365 days why?

Tags: apache

Hi I have Apache server on Centos and installed the latest stable version of mod_pagespeed module.

I'm noticing that it automatically adds browser caching of 365 days to all my image, css files etc! It's overriding my browser cache directives on my .htaccess file as well. I confirmed this by disabling the mod_pagespeed to off and checked for browser caching and none were 365 days then.

How do I specify in pagespeed.conf to stop browser caching my files? There is an option extend_cache I tried disabling that option but it's not working.

Please assist. Thanks!

Comment: Did you purge the cache once you had disabled extend_cache?

Comment: Purge which cache modpagespeed? If so what's the best way to purge the modpagespeed cache? Thanks

Comment: So I tried adding the following in mod_pagespeed pagespeed.conf file:ModPagespeedModifyCachingHeaders off
ModPagespeedDisableFilters extend_cache

Comment: The settings above just don't work! it keeps browser caching for 365 days!

Comment: That's not how you flush the CACHE. Settings does not flush your CACHE, you need to manually do that via the command line. Refer to Pagespeed documentation.

Comment: The Google PageSpeed engine was made for speeding up your website not slowing it down, The CSS/JS/PNG/JPEG files, I my experience do not change and there is no trouble with havibg the cache set to a year. In fact I set my own server caches to the same limit. I you need the need to keep lower, non-optimised caches, please remove the pagespeed module. In any case, keeping the static files cached for a year is not a bad thing!